# Duplicate writing to mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am having an issue with duplicate writings to my db.
I have a selector clause that should enforce only one answer per (question, user) but somehow there's still duplicate answers in the array.

This bug passes the tests on our local machines and happens only in production with a mass of users.

Based on [mongo's docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/write-operations-atomicity/), atomicity of `update` should take care of the test-and-set property for the concurrent requests, but there is still duplicated entries in the doc's events array if the user sends more than one request.

Here is my code:

```
playerAnswer(qId, aId) {
  Game.update(
    {
      $and: [
        { _id: this._id },
        {
          gameLog: {
            $not: {
              $elemMatch: {
                nameType: eventTypes.QuestionEnd,
                questionId: qId,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          gameLog: {
            $elemMatch: {
              nameType: eventTypes.QuestionStart,
              questionId: qId,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          gameLog: {
            $not: {
              $elemMatch: {
                nameType: eventTypes.PlayerAnswer,
                playerId: Meteor.userId(),
                questionId: qId,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          gameLog: {
            $elemMatch: {
              nameType: eventTypes.PlayerReg,
              playerId: Meteor.userId(),
            },
          },
        },
        {
          'quiz.owner': { $ne: Meteor.userId() },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      $push: {
        gameLog: new PlayerAnswer({
          playerId: Meteor.userId(),
          questionId: qId,
          answerId: aId,
        }),
      },
    },
  );
  const isEveryoneAnswered = Game.findOne(this._id).isAllPlayerAnsweredToQuestion(qId);
  return isEveryoneAnswered && this.questionEnd(qId);
}
```

As you can see from the code, the user is able to send is answer only if he didn't send one already:

```
{
   gameLog: {
     $not: {
       $elemMatch: {
         nameType: eventTypes.PlayerAnswer,
         playerId: Meteor.userId(),
         questionId: qId,
       },
     },
   },
 },
```

Comment: The logic is flawed. You are "pushing" the combination of `playerId, questionId, and answerId`, but none of your conditions look for "that" combination, or a valid "subset" of such as `playerId, questionId`. Presumably at least two of those three make "unique" and therefore should be the **only** conditions valid to check on the array before deciding whether to match the document and add a new array entry.

Comment: Does not the selector should enforce that uniqueness ?

Comment: No it does not. And it does not for the exact reasons I have described. You have other conditions there ( all of which you do not need ) which are clearly not looking at the actual part that makes the item "unique". If you still cannot work it out, show a document and what you want to attempt to add and show why something should be added and something should not. As far as I can tell, the three keys I mention must make up "uniqueness" in some combination. And that's what you are never checking. You cannot "pick two and something else". Its either "two of" or "all three".

Comment: I don't see any flaws in his logic. He is looking to update an array inside a document which does not contain a combination of the `playerId` and `questionId`. He is pushing the user and its answer only if the user didn't answer before, which enforce a document that contain the `playerId` and the `questionId`.